# Set toUrlEncodedFormData in submitForm jss sitecore forms

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms, jss-forms

I'm trying to set the content type request of the formdata but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    async onFormSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
       ....

      const formData = serializeForm(this.nextForm || this.form, {
        submitButtonName: this.submitButtonName,
      });

      formData.mergeOverwritingExisting(fieldValues);
      formData.toUrlEncodedFormData() // <--- it converts here but doesn't get applied when I submit the form. Content Type is still set to multipart.
      try {
        const result = await submitForm(formData, this.action, {
          fetcher: FormFetcher,
        });

      ... 
      } catch (error) {
        this.$emit('submit-form-error', error);
      }
    },
```

Package Version:

```
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-forms": "^21.2.4",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue": "~21.2.4",
```

[image]